# function rest parameter and generic

Tags: typescript, function, loops, generics, iterator

i have the following error in my iteration

> Operator '+=' cannot be applied to types 'number' and 'T'.

i don't no why

```
let a: number = 1, b: number = 2, c: number = 3, d: number = 4;
function somme<T>(...nombres: T[]): T {
  let s: number = 0;

  for (let nombre of nombres) {
    s += nombre;
  }
  return s;
}

console.log(a + `  + ` + b + ` = ` + somme<number>(a, b));
// 1 + 2 = 3
console.log(a + `  + ` + b + `  + ` + c + `  = ` + somme<number>(a, b, c));
// 1 + 2 + 3 = 6
console.log(a + `  + ` + b + `  + ` + c + `  + ` + d + `  = ` + somme<number>(a, b, c, d));
// 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 = 10
```

Thanks you for youre help

Comment: Why are you using generics here? What if the parameters are of some type other than number?

Comment: I thought we should use generics for all function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an error because `+` operator is restricted for two primary types `string` and `number`, you can use it only for these two or subtypes like `1` or `abc`. In your case its visible you want to work with `number` type only (you have local `s` of this type), I propose to remove generic type because this function always works with numbers:

```
function somme(...nombres: number[]): number {
  let s: number = 0;

  for (let nombre of nombres) {
    s += nombre;
  }
  return s;
}
```

Eventually you can keep generic (still see no reason), but not for return, as return is a sum, and not the same number you get as argument:

```
function somme<T extends number>(...nombres: T[]): number {
  let s: number = 0;

  for (let nombre of nombres) {
    s += nombre;
  }
  return s;
}
```

You cannot have return type `T` because it would mean that if you say `T = 1` then return would be `1`, and in reality would be sum of all `1` value in the given as argument array, so the sum would be `T * arr['length']` and such type is not possible in TS because there is no such thing like type arithmetic operations.

Comment: thank you Maciej , your code work fine , i appreciate your explanation.